# Magento 2: Show/Hide product attribute based on other attribute value

Tags: magento2, attributes, product-attribute, custom-attributes

I created two custom attributes for product. One attribute is of type drop down and other attribute is of type multi select. I want to hide multi select type attribute when drop down attribute is selected as 'no' otherwise i want to display that multi select type attribute.

Please provide me solution for this.